# Prove that $\int_0^\infty xf(x) dx = a$ and $0<f<1$ implies $\int_0^\infty xf(x) dx > \frac{a^2}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Suppose that $f \in C[0,\infty), 0 < f(x) < 1, \displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx = a$. Proof that $$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx > \dfrac{a^2}{2}$$
Here is my attempt: 
I try to proof that $$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx > \displaystyle \int_0^a x dx $$ but I got stuck

Comment: I don't get it... the integral you are trying to prove that is $> \frac {a^2} 2$ is given as $=a$. What exactly are you trying to prove? Is it possible that you were mistaken in the assumptions?

Comment: Perhaps you additionally want to have $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = 1$?

Comment: For the two conditions to be true ($\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx > \dfrac{a^2}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xf(x) dx = a$) then $2>a>0$. So you need to prove the integral is in that range. Proving that it's $>0$ is straightforward but proving it is $<2$ escapes me.

Comment: Something must be wrong with the preconditions. If $f(x) = .9$ then the integral and $a$ is infinite. But $\infty \not \ge \infty^2/2$ for any cardinality of infinity I'm aware of. This counter-example shows the assertion can't be proven.

Comment: I guess they suppose $a$ is finite.

Comment: @GuachoPerez That certainly makes sense. But what if $a=3$, then the inequality doesn't hold. My point is that it seems like some other pre-condition is necessary, like what Ian suggested.

Comment: I agree, otherwise I have no idea how we could prove the integral is bounded by $2$